# What are the regional terms for the game known as backgammon?

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-regionales

What is the game known as *backgammon* in English called in various regions?

Answer (score 1):

#### España

De acuerdo a [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backgammon):

- tablas reales
- chaquete
- chanchullo

#### México

- tric trac *[disputed]*

Comment: Aparente001, tú añadiste "tric trac" en la primera versión de este post. Te importaría verificar lo indicado por Walen en su comentario y actualizar el post de manera correspondiente? Gracias.

Comment: @diego y walen - Unfortunately I can't document my answer. 
 I played a game with acquaintances and they called it *tric trac*; it was the same as the game known in the US as *backgammon*; it's possible that the acquaintances had learned the game from someone in the US, but weren't aware they were misusing the term.  I don't know how widespread the association is in Mexico between the backgammon rules and the name *tric trac*.  That association might have been localized to the particular locale I was visiting.